# ASP.NET MVC3 Binding to a collection does not generate client side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, gridview, devexpress

I have the following model:

```
public class FacturaIntrareModel
    {
        private List<DetaliiFacturaIntrareModel> _produse = new List<DetaliiFacturaIntrareModel>();
        public List<DetaliiFacturaIntrareModel> Produse
        {
            get { return _produse; }
            set { _produse = value; }
        }
    }

public class DetaliiFacturaIntrareModel
    {


        [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Discount must have positive values!")]        
        public decimal Discount { get; set;}


    }
```

The code for the binding is this:

```
@model  FacturaIntrareModel
@using DevExpress.Data
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{


    settings.Columns.Add(col =>
    {
        col.FieldName = produsId;

        col.Caption = "Discount";
        col.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.Default;
        col.SetDataItemTemplateContent
            (c =>
            {
                string idProdus = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, produsId).ToString();
                var index = Model.Produse.FindIndex(y => y.IdProdus.ToString() == idProdus);
                ViewContext.Writer.Write
                    (
                        @Html.TextBoxWithCustomHtmlAttributesFor(x => x.Produse[index].Discount, new { @onchange = "setDiscountProdus(" + idProdus + ", $(this).val())", @style = textBoxWitxh }).ToHtmlString()
                        +
                        @Html.ValidationImageWithTooltipFor(x => x.Produse[index].Discount).ToHtmlString()

                    );
            }
            );
        col.Width = texBoxColWidth;
        col.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = textBoxColAlign;

    });


}
            ).Bind(Model.Produse).GetHtml()
```

The html generated for DISCOUNT is:

```
<input data-type="decimal" id="Produse_1__Discount" name="Produse[1].Discount" onchange="setDiscountProdus(2, $(this).val())" style="width:40px;" type="text" value="2">
<div class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Produse[1].Discount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></div>
```

No html annotations for the `RANGE` annotation have been generated.

Comment: please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239995/mvc-3-client-side-validation-on-collection-with-data-annotations-not-working 
it's not issue with devex because I had the same issue with simple html table and TextBoxFor

Comment: just tried wih `@HtmlTextBoxFor` and it rendered this `<input type="text" value="" name="Discount" id="Discount" data-val-required="The Discount field is required." data-val-range-min="0" data-val-range-max="1.79769313486232E+308" data-val-range="The Discount must have positive values!" data-val-number="The field Discount must be a number." data-val="true" class="input-validation-error">`

Comment: @Yasser , I have put HtmlTextBoxFor and no change in the HTML. The TextBoxWithCustomHtmlAttributesFor uses HtmlTextBoxFor at its core.

Comment: @YaroslavBigus , interesting, but I am inside the DevExpress GridView Settings, which is a bit harder to implement